# Fetch Check Constraint Definition in mariadb

Tags: mariadb, check-constraints

Is there any way to fetch the definition of a check constraint in mariadb?
For example,
In a constraint defined like this

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`.`bar` ( `a` INT(12) NOT NULL , CONSTRAINT `a` CHECK (`a` >= '12'));
```

I want to get the definition `(`a`>= '12')`.

I know it stores the information about this constraint in information_schema.table_constraints, but it doesn't store the definition.

But mysqldump of a database shows check constraint statements as well, so it must store it somewhere, is there any way to fetch it??

Answer (score 0):

It seems not easy to obtain that information, as mentioned in [MariaDB 10.2 CHECK and DEFAULT clauses](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/07/29/mariadb-10-2-check-and-default-clauses/) (Percona Database Performance Blog):

> Another limitation is that CHECK metadata are not accessible via the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The only way to find out if a table has CHECK
>   clauses is parsing the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE.

There is already a task or feature request to include it in future versions, see [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14474).

As an idea, the use of the `CONNECT engine` can be useful here, [Introduction to the CONNECT Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/introduction-to-the-connect-engine/):

```sql
MariaDB [none]> SELECT VERSION();
+------------------+
| VERSION()        |
+------------------+
| 10.3.8-MariaDB-1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [none]> SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+-----
| Engine             | ... 
+--------------------+-----
| MRG_MyISAM         | ... 
| CSV                | ... 
| MEMORY             | ... 
| MyISAM             | ...
| CONNECT            | ...
| Aria               | ...
| InnoDB             | ...
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | ...
| SEQUENCE           | ...
+--------------------+-----
9 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE SERVER `_`
    -> FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER MYSQL
    -> OPTIONS
    -> (
    ->   HOST '<YOUR_IP>'
    -> , USER '<YOUR_USER>'
    -> , PASSWORD '<YOUR_PASSWORD>'
    -> , PORT <YOUR_PORT>
    -> , DATABASE '<YOUR_SCHEMA>'
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> USE `_`;
Database changed

MariaDB [_]> CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `bar` (
    ->   `a` INT(12) NOT NULL,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `a` CHECK (`a` >= '12')
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `show_create_table`
    ->   ENGINE=CONNECT
    ->   TABLE_TYPE=MYSQL
    ->   SRCDEF='SHOW CREATE TABLE `bar`'
    ->   CONNECTION='_';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT TRIM(
    ->   LEADING 'CHECK ' FROM
    ->     REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    ->       (SELECT `Create table`
    ->       FROM `show_create_table`),
    ->       'CHECK[^\\n]*'
    ->     )
    -> ) `CHECK`;
+---------------+
| CHECK         |
+---------------+
| (`a` >= '12') |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Here you will have to modify the regular expression according to the complexity of your need.